# how can i apply css for javafx table column cell

Tags: css, javafx

I would like to know which css class I can use to color a table cell column.
I would like to generate columns and cells into java code.
I would like to have something like this:

```
."the class cell"
{
    -fx-background-color:black;
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a style class to the `TableColum`. This adds the style class to all `TableCell`s of this column:

```
column.getStyleClass().add("colored-column");
```

```css
.table-cell.colored-column {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: **Note:** If you use a `TreeTableView`, use `.tree-table-cell` as selector instead.

Comment: **Also note:** Make sure not to have a blank space between `.table-cell.colored-column` (i.e. not `.table-cell .colored-column`).